# Using lookup function after updating DE returns old value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup, marketingcloudapi

I've encountered quite strange phenomena. When retrieving a field from a DE and then updating this field to some other value - the lookup which follows the update function returns the old value (before the update occurred). This is done in Cloudpages.

Example:

```
%%[
set @update='1000'
set @lookup1=Lookup("Test_Source_DE","test_duplicates","contactKey", '123')
set @update=UpdateData("Test_Source_DE",1,"contactKey", '123', "test_duplicates", 'New Value')

if @update=='1' then
set @lookup2=Lookup("Test_Source_DE","test_duplicates","contactKey", '123')
endif
]%%
%%=v(@lookup1)=%% <br/>
%%=v(@lookup2)=%% <br/>
%%=v(@update)=%%
```

The printed values are:

```
"Old Value"
"Old Value"
1
```

Notice the DE update has been indeed updated to 'New Value'. It seems like the order this ampscript block is executed is as follows:

1. Execute all lookup functions (no matter the order they appear or if they're included within an `IF` condition)
2. Execute other function.

Any explanation why this is happening? Is there a way to get the expected output:

```
"Old Value"
"New Value"
1
```

Thanks

Comment: Approximately how many rows are in the data extension you're updating?  And also why are you doing a string comparison on a number -- `if @update=='1'`?

Comment: SFMC has some annoying caching on small DEs that cause problems with AMPscript update functions (updateDE, updateData, claimRow, etc).  It can be disabled via business rule, I believe.

Comment: Thanks Adam. The DE has 1 row only. The `if` statment is only to make sure the last lookup function executed after the `updatedata` data function. Regarding disabling via bussiness rule - so this caching can be disabled via support case? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, via support case.  I don't recall the name of the rule off the top of my head.